# Asking questions of examiners in PhD thesis defense?

Tags: phd, thesis-committee, defense

I have my PhD defense coming up and understand that I'll be asked if I have any questions for the examination committee, like asking for advice on turning chapters into publications.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm completely stumped!

FYI the defense includes just myself and a small examination committee (three people) so no audience, peers etc.

Comment: Which country and discipline?

Comment: Are you interested in staying in academia (or turning the chapters into publications)? If no, just say "no questions".

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can ask for advice on post-PhD life? Assuming you're pretty confident that you'll pass your exam (and your advisor shouldn't have allowed you to defend if they didn't think you were 100% going to pass!), your next step will be getting a job or postdoc somewhere. Perhaps you can ask the committee what they found most important during their first few years post-defense?

Answer (score 0):

You may ask their opinion of how to continue the topic being covered by your PhD thesis or how they see the application of it. I expect that your work is somehow closed, but you may get interesting advise you don't see now.